# How do I get shaded textbox when form validation fails?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

This code is from a form in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Using the code below, when the form field FirstName is blank, the error message is displayed in Red.
What do I need to do, to get the text box to have the red border and shaded background that is common on sites?

Thanks for any help on this.

Model class field:

```
 [Required (ErrorMessage ="You must enter a first name")]
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Form field:

```
 <div class="form-row">
     <label for="FirstName" class="col-3 col-form-label">Number of users to process:</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-6 form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

Comment: have you tried : `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { @class = "text-danger border" })` ?border is a bootstrap class.

Comment: @user3807918: If you add some screen-shot of the text box with the red border and shaded background, like what you need, this will help to understand exactly what you want to see on your form.

Answer (score 0):

add this css class

```
.validation-shadow
{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #ddd;   /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 2px #ddd;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 2px #ddd;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

and this code

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { @class = "text-danger validation-shadow" })
```